# Zed camera with Android phone/tablet

Tags: android, camera

On the [website](https://support.stereolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/207641625-Can-I-use-the-ZED-camera-on-Android-) it says that even though there is no SDK provided for android it is possible to connect it to the android device with a micro-USB adapter. Is it possible to extract images from both cameras of ZED in this case? Is so, any code samples to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted the ZED Support Team and receive the following reply:

> You need to connect the camera to the USB port (but note that it will
>   behave in USB2 mode).Then to extract the side by side image of the
>   ZED, you need to do some JNI in C (Java/Android does not allow native
>   grabbing from USB). To do so, you can find on github a libuvc wrapper
>   for android that reads UVC camera such as the ZED. (
>   https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera )

Enjoy!